# foldername and Foldername in git - how to merge and keep history

Tags: git, gitlab

somehow I ended up with foldername and Foldername (case sensitive problem) in the same git repo.  Both folders have files in them with history.  Will the following code merge Foldername files into foldername without losing the files in foldername?

```
git mv Foldername tmp
git mv tmp foldername
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second command will fail because `foldername` already exists.  You can merge the folder contents with one command:

```
git mv Foldername/* foldername/
```

This will preserve file history.  When `Foldername` is empty it's basically ignored by git because it only cares about the files within each folder.  You can remove the extra folder with `rm Foldername`.